# Open source bitcoin desktop wallet for Windows

Tags: windows, gratis, open-source, software-development, cryptocurrency

I am looking for **best cryptocurrency desktop wallet**. Could anyone suggest me a wallet for these digital currencies? Plus if you know open-source project for developing this kind of desktop application for cryptocurrency then give me some links to participate in.it will enhance my software development skills.

Comment: OS? Budget? What currencies do you participate in?

Comment: windows-need free soft-just bitcoin.

Comment: I added the [tag:windows] and [tag:gratis] tags for you. In future, take more care with operating system and budget - the more information that you give, the more we can help you. Take a look at [ask]. And, welcome aboard :-)

Comment: Which ones have you tried, and what is wrong with them?

Comment: @NicolasRaoul I didn't try anyone yet. but i am little concerned about security and reliability.

Comment: @Mawg thanks. I forgot OS(windows) tag.

Comment: And don't forget, in future to use the [tag:gratis] tag or to state a budget. Some recommendations here are for software which costs thousands. That might be acceptable to you, or it might not. How are we to know if you don't tell us? It's always best when you help us to help you ;-)

Comment: i add open-source tag i think that's pretty much the same thing what  [tag:gratis]  says.